# Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string

Tags: regex, expression, hour, seconds, minute

I want to parse a `hh:mm:ss` string.
A simple one is `([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)`  which expects `2:3:24` or `02:03:24` string.

I want to take it a step further and pass the validation even in cases like

1. if you enter just 56, it should be pass, as 56 can be considered as 56 secs  [SS]
2. if you enter 2:3 or 02:03 or 02:3 or 2:03  it should pass. 2 minutes and 3 seconds [MM:SS]
3. If you enter 20:30:12 pass with 20 hrs, 30 minutes and 12 secs [HH:MM:SS]
4. if you enter 78:12 , do not pass  78 minutes is wrong....

Basically, if one ":" is found, consider number before ":" as MM and number after ":" as SS
. If two ":" are found consider as HH:MM:SS

I came up with this pattern.

```
(^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)$)|(^([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)$)|(^[0-5]?\d$)
```

It seems to be working fine. I wanted to know any other simpler regular expression, that can do the job.

Comment: For your requirements, that looks like a remarkably simple regex.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # Start of string
(?:                 # Try to match...
 (?:                #  Try to match...
  ([01]?\d|2[0-3]): #   HH:
 )?                 #  (optionally).
 ([0-5]?\d):        #  MM: (required)
)?                  # (entire group optional, so either HH:MM:, MM: or nothing)
([0-5]?\d)          # SS (required)
$                   # End of string
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is much simpler and cool. I want to learn regex. Please point me in right direction. How do I learn regex.  All I currently know is basic syntax (Quick tutorial kind of stuff)

Comment: @user418836: Check out www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: how can i use this in posix c for the regcomp function. i get an unkown excape sequence at '\d'

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: Try `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: Dint work .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428586/c-posix-regex-to-validate-input-hhmmss-time-string

Comment: Wonderful explanation. If you also want to match decimal seconds, it's easy to add that as well: `^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)(?:\.(\d+))?$`, try it [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D)%3A)%3F(%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd)%3A)%3F(%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd)(%3F%3A%5C.(%5Cd%2B))%3F%24&test_string=10%3A34%3A23.414&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: How to use ^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$ pattern in ng-pattern

Comment: @bcattle you probably meant `^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)(\.(\d{1,9}))?$` - the milliseconds are usually presented only after a point ... if at all

Answer (score 15):

@Tim Pietzcker covers the OP's requirement for a HH:MM:SS parser where SS was mandatory, i.e.

- HH:MM:SS
- MM:SS
- SS

If you permit me to deviate from the OP's requirement for a bit, and consider a case where HH is mandatory, i.e.

- HH
- HH:MM
- HH:MM:SS

The regex I came up with was:

```
^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?$
```

Let's break it down:

- `([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])` - matches for hours
- `(?::([0-5]?\d))?` - optionally matches for minutes
- `(?::([0-5]?\d))?` - optionally matches for seconds

Comment: This matches H:M:S as opposed to only HH:MM:SS