# c posix regex to validate input HH:MM:SS time string

Tags: c, regex, validation, time, posix

Related to [Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string)
I am trying to validate user time input.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];
        char inputStr2[100]="12:34:04";
        char inputStr[100]="12:34";

/* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?[0-9]):)?([0-5]?[0-9])$", 0);
        if( reti ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        }

/* Execute regular expression */
           printf("%s is the string\n",inputStr);
        reti = regexec(&regex, inputStr, 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        }
         printf("%s is the string\n",inputStr2);
        reti = regexec(&regex, inputStr2, 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        }
/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

1. i get the error unknown escape sequence '\d'.

whats wrong here? Is this the best way to go about validating user time input?.
Edit:
Tried with `"^(?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)$"` and i get a no match.
Also with

Comment: This does not handle the case of `24:00:00` ([midnight at the end of the day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)), or `23:59:60` ([leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)). And that's assuming that you only want to support times down to second precision.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling how would you do it then?

Comment: use [`strptime(%T)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian nice its simpler . but what do you figure is wrong above involving the usage of regexec ?

Comment: Your regex (in the edited post) doesn't contain a `\d` anymore, so I guess the error message you posted is not the actual error message you're currently getting. Can you tell us the real problem?

Comment: @TimPietzcker the expression does not evaluate the string to  match. There is no error message.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `strptime()`, for example

```
struct tm t;
char p;

p = strptime(inputStr, "%H:%M:%S", &t);

if (p == NULL || *p != '\0') {
    abort();
}
```

Comment: that's what i did when J.F.Sebastian suggested it first.

Answer (score 1):

A POSIX regular expression engine does not support non-capturing groups `(?:...)`. Use normal groups instead:

```
^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?[0-9]):)?([0-5]?[0-9])$
```

I don't have gcc installed. If the underlying regex engine is a POSIX BRE instead of a POSIX ERE (as I thought), then a different syntax is needed (because parentheses are treated as literals unless escaped, and POSIX BREs don't know the `?` quantifier:

```
^\(\(\([01]\{0,1\}[0-9]|2[0-3]\):\)\{0,1\}\([0-5]\{0,1\}[0-9]\):\)\{0,1\}\([0-5]\{0,1\}[0-9]\)$
```

or, as a string:

```
"^\\(\\(\\([01]\\{0,1\\}[0-9]|2[0-3]\\):\\)\\{0,1\\}\\([0-5]\\{0,1\\}[0-9]\\):\\)\\{0,1\\}\\([0-5]\\{0,1\\}[0-9]\\)$"
```

Comment: Are you aware that the regex is designed to match `HH:MM:SS` or `MM:SS` or `SS`? So `59:59` is a valid match. If that's OK for your requirements, fine.

Comment: sorry but i still get a no match, I am aware what the regex is desined to match. have you run the code gcc ? thats the entire program.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: Perhaps the underlying regex engine is only a POSIX BRE? I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: I missed something: `?` doesn't exist in POSIX BREs, so it needs to be changed to `\{0,1\}`. With this, your program works, at least for match no. 1 - no idea why ideone says it fails for match no. 2.

Comment: +1 Its the same at my side posix gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) . At least this is partially working.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write `\` and then a letter compiler thinks it's a special character like `\n` (new line symbol) or `\t` (tab symbol). And there is no `\d` symbol that's why you're getting an error. You should write `\\d` if you mean "a digit". Actually you just need to escape the backslash (`\` is the escape character in C, C++, Java, C# and many other languages).
For example this stirng `"abc\n\\d"` actually is `"abc[enter]\d"` in memory. So when you right `\\d` in pattern in fact it's kept in memory as `\d`, actually what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `\` is an escape character in a string, you have to double it to get the escape character in a regex ie `\\`.

Try this:

```
"^(?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)$"
```