# Regex for hh:mm:ss tt string

Tags: sql-server, regex, datetime

I've looked at a few regex time questions but haven't found one that I need and I'm pretty clueless on how to write regex expressions.

I need time values like this to pass:

- 06:03:05 AM
- 06:03 pm
- 6:3:5 AM

This regex seems like it'd work for this(which I found on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string)  but I also need to have the AM/PM part required but it can also be case insensitive.

```
([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)
```

So to sum up what I need in this regex:

- single digit h:m:s acceptable
- double digit hh:mm:ss acceptable
- AM/PM required but case insensitive
- if the AM/PM part can be entered as a or p would be nice, but not needed
- seconds are optional
- 24 hour time not acceptable

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you using regex in SQL Server? CLR?

Comment: What about 24 hour time?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - These times will be saved into a SQL server. I have a different part of the program which sets the current time with a button, so I didn't need any regex there, but I also need to allow for editing of times in back end.

Comment: @jonnyGold - I'm not using 24 hour time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you provide supports 24 hour time, the following my stringently follows your request

```
(1[012]|0?\d):[0-5]?\d(:[0-5]?\d)?\s+[AaPp][Mm]?
```

Comment: Working great, does that final ? at the end make the am/pm optional?

Comment: It makes the [Mm] optional, so that AM/PM can be added as A or P

Answer (score 1):

Just add `?` after the seconds part and `\s+[aApP][mM]` at the end of the re:

```
([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)(:([0-5]?\d))?\s+[aApP][mM]
```

And when you don't neet 24h format change the first part:

```
(1[0-2]|0?\d):([0-5]?\d)(:([0-5]?\d))?\s+[aApP][mM]
```

Comment: They said no military time, which I'm going to assume means they are american and mean 24 hour clock.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr - Sorry about that, I've edited my question to clarify that.