# How to convert standard regex to php regex?

Tags: php, regex

After searching on web for validating time as "HH:MM:SS" I found this:
[Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string). but when i put it in my php code i get an error:

```
preg_match("^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$", "12:33:51", $matches);
```

this is my error message

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in db-dataitem.php on line 128

How could I change the pattern string so it can work for PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a delimiter:

```
preg_match("/^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$/", "12:33:51", $matches);
```

-in PHP pattern is expected [to be delimited](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) from modifiers. That delimiter should be non-alphanumeric.

But (as it was done in another good answer) - it's much better to use proper tool for your problem - i.e. validate timestamp via `DateTime` API.

Answer (score 6):

## DATETIME SOLUTION

You can validate all your date/time strings with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

### Function

```
function isTimeValid($time, $format = 'H:i:s') {
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time);
    return $dt && $dt->format($format) == $time;
}
```

This function can be used for all datetime-combination validation. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322824/php-preg-match-with-working-regex/12323025#12323025)

### Example

```
foreach (['12:30:54', '13:30:65', '00:00:00', '00:70:00'] as $time) {
    echo "Time '$time' is " . (isTimeValid($time) ? "" : "not ") . "valid.\n";
}
```

### Example output

```
Time '12:30:54' is valid.
Time '13:30:65' is not valid.
Time '00:00:00' is valid.
Time '00:70:00' is not valid.
```

Comment: I just love this solution, the right tool, for the right job! Plus I learned something today!

Comment: thanks, I voted you, this solved my problem,yet i have to give the mark to the right answer related to the question.

Comment: @EhsanErshadi: ofc. If you will need other kind of datetime validation, you can use this function. [Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322824/php-preg-match-with-working-regex/12323025#12323025).

Comment: @Glavić seems you play a lot with datetime :) +1

Comment: @swapnesh: hehe, true ;) I had a lot of DateTime related projects ;)