# I need a RegEx for validationg a time format HH:MM:SS:mm

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I want to check an input in a form to validate this format.

I use this RegEx but it doesn't work like i want ( to be in this format HH:MM:SS:mm )

HH : hours
MM : minutes
SS : seconds
mm : milliseconds

```
/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:\\.([0-9]{1,3}))?$/i
```

I have used the jquery validation plugin for testing the form, this is the example of method that i create including this RegEx :

```
$.validator.addMethod("timeFormat", function(value, element) {  
                return this.optional(element) || /^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:\\.([0-9]{1,3}))?$/i.test(value);  
            }, "");
```

what's wrong with this ?

Comment: This is an extremely simple regex. The fact that you ask us to write it for you shows that you are too lazy to read even the most simple regex introduction tutorial and do not show the "minimal understanding" required to ask us for code.

Comment: No, it's just that i can't figure out how to make it right, i had tested this /^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:\\.([0-9]{1,3}))?$/i but it doesn't work like i want :(

Comment: See, now include that regex in your question and tell us why it didn't work. Then we can re-open it.

Comment: Also show us some input that should work but didn't

Comment: Try this regex

`\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}`

Comment: @user1671639 Is `99:99:99:99` a valid time? The OP should just replace `?:\\.([0-9]{1,3})` with `:\d{2}`.

Comment: @RobW Agreed. just wanted to show a quick try

Comment: closely related to  [Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string)

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(:|\.)\d{2}
```

[Regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/nwnplxs)

Comment: that's not working in last 2 digits of milliseconds ?? i have tested this and it's work but in milliseconds it can be 99 maximun :
([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])

Comment: @kach can you try this `([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(:|\.)([0-9]{1,2})`

Comment: @kach I too checked this `([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(:|\.)\d{2}`  this seems fine

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2}:\d{1,3}
```

(Milliseconds may be up to three digits)