# Javascript regex matching on a time

Tags: javascript

I want to see if the string I have is in the form of HH:MM:SS.

Here is what I have so far:

```
d = '00:01:01'
d.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)
["00:01:02"]
```

Is there a way to just get a True/False, instead of an array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string

check this

Comment: an array is "true-ish" ... so you can still check `if(d.match(...))`

Comment: How would I do that then @devnull69

Comment: ahem ... I just told you, didn't I? You just need to replace the `...` in my answer with the RegEx you already have

Comment: you can also use .test() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/3B4zp/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you can use [regex.test(str)](http://jsfiddle.net/3B4zp/5/) but it's also possible using `match` because on success, `match` returns an `array` which is a `truthy` value and on failure, `match` returns `null` which is a `falsy` value. Check this to understand [truthy and falsy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

So, if you use

```
if(d.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)) {
    // true
}
else {
    // false
}
```

This will work, check this fiddle as [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3B4zp/4/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) as well (about `!!`), I've used `!!` in my example, so you may have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.test` method of Regexp object.

```
/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(d)
// true
```