# Regex pattern for EXACTLY HH:MM:SS time String

Tags: java, regex, validation, datetime

I want to validate sting time format in EXACTLY `hh:mm:ss` String.
I mean by EXACTLY that
Each of hours / minutes / seconds MUST be **2 digits**
Also 
*Accept only logical values* like

- hours [ from 00 to 23 ]
- minutes [ from 00 to 59 ]
- seconds [ from 00 to 59 ]

When i checked [Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string)
The answer accept `hh:mm:ss` string but also accepts cases like `2:3:24`

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't regex, but you can always check the length of the string, and make sure it is 9 exactly.

Comment: You do understand that `h` and `H`, and `m` and `M` have a different meaning?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)
```

This will match both "20:30:30" and "2020-05-29 20:30:30 -0600".

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/5)

If you want to only match Strings that are *exclusively* 24-hour times, use the following:

```
^(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)$
```

This will match only "20:30:30" and *not* "2020-05-29 20:30:30 -0600".

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/212)

Java regex would be,

```
(?:[01]\\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\\d):(?:[012345]\\d)
```

And for exclusively 24-hour Strings,

```
^(?:[01]\\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\\d):(?:[012345]\\d)$
```

Comment: This regex fails to match 20:30:30 because the value of `20` at HH is considered invalid.

Comment: Another one that works: `^((?=(?:\D*\d\D*){6})(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d))$` [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vK9vM2/3)

Comment: @theftprevention Not sure if the author edited their answer but you can see in the demo that "20:30:30" matches just fine. Can you confirm the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaPinter The answer may have been edited, or I may have been wrong! Either way, my comment is no longer relevant. This was almost six years ago; time flies when you're parsing it with regex!

Comment: @theftprevention LOL. Well played sir!

Comment: Coming back to this, this also matches Strings that may contain 24-hour times but are not exclusively 24-hour times, like "2020-05-29 20:30:30 -0600". How do we ignore these lines so that only Strings with 24-hour times are matched. So it only matches "20:30:30" and not "2020-05-29 20:30:30 -0600"?

Comment: Just need to add a `^` to the start of the pattern and a `$` to the end of the pattern to signify the start and end of the String _only_. I updated the answer with this version as well in case anybody else needs it.

Answer (score 10):

Give this a try:

```
^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

[Demo available here.](http://www.regexr.com/39gqd)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you want is:

```
(([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

which is for `HH:MM:SS` **24** hour format.