# PHP regex to match various hh:mm:ss video durations

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I can't get a regex match when there is an hour value given. How can I get a possible hour to match (with or without leading zero)?

```
$val = '01:04:06'; // doesn't match
$val = '1:04:06'; // doesn't match
$val = '04:06'; // matches
$val = '4:06'; // matches

preg_match("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", $val, $matches);
```

Comment: Try: `/^(\d{1,2}):\d{1,2}(?:\d{1,2})?$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the leading `^`

You can rewrite your regex as `/(\d?\d):(\d?\d)$/` if you want minutes and seconds.

If you want (optionally) the hour, write `/((\d?\d):)?(\d?\d):(\d?\d)$/` instead.

Comment: You forgot the « $ » in your test.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match it as a whole, just make a group for the first sequence until `:`, and added a quantifier, so it could happen 1 or 2 times.

`/^(([\d]{1,2})\:){1,2}([\d]{2})$/`

[Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/gS9m4V/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one from a similar stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string) but converted for preg_match:

```
preg_match("/^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$/", $val, $matches);
```