# How to validate every number in a timer with 'hh:mm:ss' format where 0<=mm,ss<=59?

Tags: python, regex

I want to validate my timerlabel which is on the format hh:mm:ss and so far i have done it by this:

```
if re.match("^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$", self._lineeditDuration.text()):
```

The problem with the above line is that the user can enter 00:99:99, which does not make sense that the minutes and seconds can be higher than 59.

Is there a way to validate each of the numbers that represents minutes, so the first number can be 0-5 and the second number can be 0-9. The same goes for seconds.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318236/6699447) helps.

Comment: Is hh in the range 00..23? 01..12? Is a leading zero optional or required?

Comment: no hh has no limits, just minutes and seconds, because after 59 they will just count again from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work
`if re.match("^[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$", self._lineeditDuration.text()):`

Comment: Except this also allows hh to be 00..59, which is wrong.  hh is either in the range 00..23? 01..12? with or without leading zero

Comment: Since this is not a time  but a timer label I think any limitation or even no limitation on hh would be OK since a 99:59:59 timer would be totally valid.

Comment: if re.match("^[0-9]{2}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$", self._lineeditDuration.text()):
this works

Answer (score 0):

00:00:00
00:00:01
23:59:17
01:01:01
10:17:25
09:56:17
22:56:59

Find and Match : ^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))$
view Test https://regex101.com/r/qokOxD/1

Comment: This regex is not satisfying the constraints that OP has provided. "hh has no limits, just minutes and seconds" yet this regex fails for 99:00:00

Comment: correction ^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))$  https://regex101.com/r/i4KK1D/1