# Struggling to clean the column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I need help with cleaning a column of my data. So, basically in the column, in each separate cell there are dates, time, letter, floating points so many other type of data. The datatype of this column is 'Object'.

What I want to do is, remove all the dates and replace it with empty cells and keep only the time in the entire column. And then I want to insert the average time into the empty cells.

I'm using pycharm and using PANDAS to clean the column.

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Could you add a small portion of the column? Or are you looking for general advice?

Comment: 11:00:00
16:00:00


12:30:00

11:30:00
-0.2798558
15/08/2017
13:00:00
15/08/2017
13:40:00
14:00:00



12:00:00

13:30:00

14:30:00

12:10:00
09:00:00

11:00:00
07:30:00
18:30:00


07:30:00
10:45:00

09:00:00

11:00:00
07/03/2007
16/05/2007
08:00:00

09:30:00
07:30:00
10:00:00

09:00:00
09:00:00
07:30:00
08:00:00
15:00:00
10:00:00
07:40:00
11:10:00
10:00:00
07:40:00

07:40:00
10/10/2009
14:45:00

07:30:00
14:20:00

07:30:00

07:45:00
11:00:00

12:29:00
-0.570358
07:32:00
14:34:00
P
09:00:00
12:26:00
12:40:00

Comment: Each of the value is in the separate cell (like excel, I'm working on .csv file). I want to get rid letter, float values, dates. And just leave the time .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use `df["your_col"].str.match(time_regex)` to match every cell against a regex pattern. That will return a series of True and False in case a match was found. You can use that series to either remove cells or overwrite them.

Comment: That is assuming that all entries are strings. You can yoink a regex from e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string

Comment: I have added the picture. Could you please have a look.

Comment: The image does not help us

Comment: What should I upload?

Comment: Are you able to send me a youtube video where I can see how can I get rid to values of I dont need from the column.

Comment: Anyone there who can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you can achieve this with something along the lines of below. For time format, it seems like for your data column just checking if string contains 2 semi colons is enough. You can also specify something more robust:

```
def string_splitter (x):
   x=x.split()
   y=[]
   for stuff in x:
      if stuff.index(":")>1: #<you can also replace with a more robust pattern for time>
          y.append(stuff)
      else:
          y.append("")#<add your string for indicating empty space>
return " ".join(y)

df['column_name'].apply(string_splitter)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This what I'm getting "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: I assumed your column is a string to be able to store that many different values in one column, but it seems like I misunderstood the question...is there a way for you to post  outputs of df.info() and df.head() into the question (if the data is not sensitive)?